# Can we gift users rep for answering a question that should be deleted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A short while back I asked a [ridiculously simple question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133807/how-do-i-create-a-numbered-list-with-php?noredirect=1) and it was marked as "On Hold - Off Topic". Looking at it I realized I should have known the answer, but as I tried to make clear I was having an off day.

That being said, TF answered my question quickly - providing a much needed boost to my day. If the Q&A is deleted, they'll lose the few rep points they earned by answering. Now I understand they user in question has ~4,500 rep points and the 15 I'd be willing to give up isn't much in comparison, but I would really like to give 15 of my own rep to them. Any thoughts/answers or should this be more of a feature request?

Answer (score 5):

We will not delete questions with accepted answers if they could be remotely helpful for other users, not even when they are off topic. So in your case, the problem doesn’t exist. :)

In other cases … we don’t want to encourage our members to answer off topic questions, because that would send the wrong message: You can ask *any* question here, if it is simple you might get an answer, even if the question is off topic.

That would hurt our site.

However, you can flag a question for moderator attention and ask to migrate it to a site where it would fit better. We do that if the question is good. The reputation would be given on that site then.

Comment: I will try to give my very best not to answer any off-topic question from now on. To my defense, my fingers had already answered the question in question before I really could have thought about it... ;)